# What is this type of pivoting

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm reading the book Theory of Linear and Integer Programming and it its closely related to linear algebra. In the preliminaries it defines pivoting of matrix $A$(here $A$ is of arbitrary size, $\alpha$ is a real number $b$ is a row vector, $c$ a column vector and $D$ a matrix, all of proper dimensions):

\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha &b\\
c & D
\end{bmatrix}

over the pivot element $\alpha$ as follows:

\begin{bmatrix}
-\alpha^{-1}& \alpha^{-1}b\\
\alpha^{-1}c& D-\alpha^{-1}cb
\end{bmatrix}

I don't know what is the purpose of this defenition(I can't even write this as a combination of elementary row and column operations, and it's not similar to normal pivoting where one would turn a whole column to zero except $\alpha$ which is turned to 1). Can you guess what this means?

Comment: I don't think it's "classical" to call this a "pivoting" operation. I have tried to write it in the following way $\begin{bmatrix}
0&0\\
0& D
\end{bmatrix} -\alpha^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}-1\\
 \ c
\end{bmatrix} [-1 \ \ b]$ but it does not bring anything close to classical pivoting.

Comment: @JeanMarie I, also, have tried to relate this to the "classical pivoting" but it seems impossible. I'm looking for any non-algebraic meaning you can decipher from this.